# never awaited (async sheduler)

Tags: python-3.x, asyncio, scheduler

Создаю планировщика рассылки, никак не пойму, как выполнить функцию, помогите пожалуйста.
Данный код:

```
import datetime as dt
import asyncio
from scheduler.asyncio import Scheduler

users = {"user1": {"morningtime" : "0900",
                   "middletime": "1500",
                   "eveningtime":"2100",
                   "tasks" : ["task1", "task2", "task3"]},
         "user2": {"morningtime" : "0900",
                   "middletime": "1500",
                   "eveningtime":"2100",
                   "tasks" : ["task4", "task5", "task6"]},
         "user3": {"morningtime" : "0900",
                   "middletime": "1500",
                   "eveningtime":"2100",
                   "tasks" : ["task7", "task8", "task9"]}}

async def foo(elem):
    print(elem)


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    schedule = Scheduler(loop=loop)
    for user in users:
        mot = users.get(user).get("morningtime")
        mit = users.get(user).get("middletime")
        evt = users.get(user).get("eveningtime")
        tasks = users.get(user).get("tasks")
        schedule.daily(timing=[dt.time(hour=int(mot[:2]), minute=int(mot[2:])),
                               dt.time(hour=int(mit[:2]), minute=int(mit[2:])),
                               dt.time(hour=int(evt[:2]), minute=int(evt[2:]))],

                       handle=foo(tasks))
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'foo' was never awaited
```

Что я делаю не так? В документации к библиотеки, ответа на мой вопрос не нашел.

Comment: Почему вы вместо `handle=foo` написали `handle=foo(tasks)`?

Comment: @andreymal Потому что мне нужно передать в foo параметр, и иного способа это сделать, на данный момент я не знаю.

Comment: Используй партиал или лямбду